# Are splash weapons improvable with a fighter's Weapon Training?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, equipment

I would assume that they are thrown weapons, but it does not appear that they are part of the thrown group. So does that mean that you cannot be weapon trained with splash weapons?

I am specifically thinking for a multi-class fighter / alchemist.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Correct; the fighter, as written, has no ability to train with splash weapons.

However, while Paizo has made an attempt to be comprehensive with their weapon training lists, there is this caveat:

> GMs may add other weapons to these groups, or add entirely new groups

So talk to your GM about either adding splash weapons to the thrown group or adding a splash weapon group. The biggest question I would have is whether the damage bonuses apply to the splash damage or only to the primary hit, but that’s the only reason to even think twice about allowing it, in my mind. (And personally, I probably would allow it to apply to the splash too.)

Answer (score 5):

## Splash weapons aren't a proficiency

[Throw Splash Weapon](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Throw-Splash-Weapon) says

> Thrown splash weapons require no weapon proficiency, so you don't take the –4 nonproficiency penalty.

Splash weapons are outside the [normal weapon list](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/weapons) and follow their own rules.

I am almost certain, however, that a GM could implement a house rule to add them to the fighter's [weapon training](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/fighter#TOC-Weapon-Training-Ex-) (either as their own entry or to thrown weapons) without unbalancing the game and turning the fighter into a powerhouse that overshadows all other PCs.

Answer (score 3):

## Yes, there's a way.

**Splash Weapons can benefit from Weapon Training...if you use a Flask Thrower.**

The [Flask Thrower](https://www.aonprd.com/EquipmentWeaponsDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Flask%20thrower) is an exotic weapon that says,

> This staff has a cradle at the end, **designed to hold alchemical weapons such as acid**. A flask thrower significantly extends the range of thrown substances that deal splash damage, such as acid, alchemist’s fire, or holy water, as well as that of tools such as tanglefoot bags, thunderstones, or caltrops.

The Flask Thrower is listed in the Thrown Weapon group, so a Fighter can certainly add Weapon Training to it.

The main caveat is that it's an Exotic weapon (unless you're a Gnome) so you have to find a way to fit in proficiency.

Comment: Proficiency is incredibly easy to come by in Pathfinder, thanks to *cracked opalescent white pyramid ioun stone* which lets you treat any one weapon as martial for a mere 1,500 gp. Grabbing a *wayfinder* for a cheap Weapon Focus is solid too. Which makes this a great answer! Just a shame they didn't reuse the 3.5e name for this weapon: *the gnomish calculus* (they probably avoided that for legal reasons but still).

Comment: There is also, by the way, the launching crossbow that has a similar property, but it’s awful (full-round action to load, so one attack every two rounds).

Comment: Crossbow Mastery can allow you to full attack with a launching crossbow, fighters are big balls of feats to qualify for it, so it could work and let you pewpew when you don't want to use bombs.

Comment: @RyanLougheed True, but... why bother? It’s 50% more range, but you’re talking about at least two feats (Rapid Reload, which a flask thrower wouldn’t need, and Crossbow Mastery) for 10 feet of range. I know Pathfinder unconscionably nerfed Far Shot but still.